# How to write dynamic xpath for img src

Tags: selenium, xpath

i am trying to automate couple of Selenium-TestNg scenarios from the website - http://ecommerce.saipratap.net/checkpersonaldetail.php

I was trying to click on the "continue "button, but it seems to be an image.
Below is the snippet of the code. How to write the xpath for the same?

tried using the xpath - //a[contains(@href,'checkoutshiping.php')], but it didnt work

```
<a href="checkoutshiping.php"> ==$0
    <img src="images/continue.gif" border="0"
     style="cursor:hand;"> ==$0
   </a>
```

Comment: share error it may be a wait issue ?

Comment: I am getting the below exception - org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using xpath=//a[@href='checkoutshiping.php']
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'LENOVO', ip: '192.168.1.101', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Comment: @ChaitanyaMaligi Instead of publishing the _error stack trace_ as a comment this should have been an edit to the main question so the contributors can have a better visibility of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the user is logged in? I see other set of tags when check the website.
[image]

Have you tried below xpath.

```
//*[.='Checkout']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use - //a[@href = "checkoutshiping.ph"], its gonna find your button. I checked it on your website.

Comment: I am getting the below exception - org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using xpath=//a[@href='checkoutshiping.php']
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'LENOVO', ip: '192.168.1.101', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Comment: Thats weird, here is example (I added screenshot) from your website, pls double check element name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example from your website
[image]